# SWT Issue in Aligning + Filling a Label with GridData

Tags: java, swt

So, I tried to make a little game where you have to do actions that are displayed by a label.

My problem is that I can't align the label in the center of a column **AND** fill the whole space of the column with the label so I can use the background cColor.

For example:

```
Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        
GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
Font font = new Font(display, "Arial", 30, SWT.NONE);

layout.numColumns = 2;
layout.marginHeight = 0;
layout.marginWidth = 0;

shell.setText("ReactionGame 2.0");
shell.setMaximized(true);
shell.setLayout(layout);
shell.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK));

GridData data1 = new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, true, true);
        
data1.verticalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
data1.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
        
Label lifelabel = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);

lifes(lifelabel);
lifelabel.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
lifelabel.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK));
lifelabel.setFont(font);

lifelabel.setLayoutData(data1);
        
Label scorelabel = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        
scorecount(scorelabel);
scorelabel.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
scorelabel.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK));
scorelabel.setFont(font);
        
scorelabel.setLayoutData(data1);
        
        Label gamelabel = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);

gamelabel.setText("");
gamelabel.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GREEN));
gamelabel.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK));
gamelabel.setFont(font);

        gamelabel.setLayoutData(data1);
```

[This code gives me a design of this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBMeF.png)

My question now is how can I align the text of the label in the center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reusing the same `GridData` (`data1`) for multiple controls - this is not allowed. The `GridData` instance is used to save layout information about individual controls, you must use a new instance for each control.

So use:

```
lifelabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, true, true));

scorelabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, true, true));

gamelabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, true, true));
```

To make the third area you will need to use an extra `Composite` with the label centred in that and a background colour set:

```
Composite gameComp = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);

gameComp.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

gameComp.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));

GridLayout gameLayout = new GridLayout();
gameLayout.marginHeight = 0;
gameLayout.marginWidth = 0;
gameComp.setLayout(gameLayout);

Label gamelabel = new Label(gameComp, SWT.NONE);

gamelabel.setText("game");
gamelabel.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GREEN));
gamelabel.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
gamelabel.setFont(font);

gamelabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, true, true));
```

Comment: I try to keep that in mind, but the problem stay's the same. When i center the label like you showed i cant completely fill the collumn like i want (shown in the picture).

Comment: Sorry missed that - see update, you need to use an extra Composite with a background colour set.